# Ipfail ignores Heartbeats command to stop

Tags: linux, heartbeat

I currently have two RHEL 6.4 servers running Heartbeat 2.1.3-3, DRDB, and Monit.

Heartbeat refuses to shut down gracefully. The "ipfail" process will not listen to heartbeat's command to stop.  During a system shutdown, this can stall the shutdown process indefinitely and the only solution is to force a reboot.

In other words, if the command "service heartbeat stop" is issued, then the "ipfail" process must be killed with signal 9.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.